# how to only allow sudo on specify path?

Tags: linux

in Linux:

I want to limited user only can do sudo on specify path.

sudo chmod works on /home/Krome/revA

but sudo chmod failed on /home/Krome

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find such section on visudo,maybe I missed

Comment: What exactly you tried??? since Krome is a Directory .... so u must have used sudo chmod -R /home/Krome??? or something else

Answer (score 1):

Restricting a user or process to a certain path can be done with `chroot` - the problem here is that after the `chroot` the commands in `$PATH` and dynamically loaded objects would no longer be accessible, so you'd need a statically linked *shell* which executes the `chroot` as well as the **built-in** commands that the user shall be able to issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it possible, and am pretty sure it's not reasonable.

`chmod` would work inside `/home/Krome` if it's the user's home folder.

I think you need a regular user (without `sudo`), and everything else can be managed by adding that user to groups and sharing some folders to those groups.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `/etc/sudoers` something like the following line:

```
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod [ugoa][-+=][rwxXst] /home/Krome/*
```

It basically says that all group `users` members can invoke `sudo chmod` in symbolic mode on anything under `/home/Krome/` path.

See `man sudo` for more details.

Comment: @maxim-yegorushkin Won't something like ```sudo chmod 777 /home/Krome/tmpfile /root``` let me chmod ```/root``` ? If so, that's a big security breach.